# How to use Are you and have you?

Tags: sentence-construction

Which sentence is correct?
When to use Are you and have you?

Are you returned from conference?
Or
Have you returned from conference?

Comment: You should get a Beginners' Grammar in book form. Grammar information on the Internet is confusing.

Answer (score 2):

It's "*Have you returned from the conference*?".

*Be* can be a helping verb with the *-ing* form of the verb (to express progressive tenses), not the *-ed* form.

For example: "*I am returning*", "*she was returning*", etc.

So, in interrogative mood, it would be "*Are you returning from the conference?*".

If you want to ask a question, but don't want to use a progressive tense, and aren't using any other helping verbs like *have*, *will*, *should*, you'll generally need to use *do* as a helping verb.

*Did you return from the conference?*